# javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed; with nested javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair

Tags: jsp, jakarta-mail, contact-form

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JSP JavaMail Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
    <%@ page import="javax.mail.*"%>
    <%@ page import="javax.mail.internet.*"%>
    <%@ page import="javax.activation.*"%>
    <%
        String to = request.getParameter("to");     
        String from = request.getParameter("email");
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String phone = request.getParameter("phone");
        String subject =request.getParameter("subject");
        String messageText = request.getParameter("message");
        //Get the session object  
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");



         Session session2 = Session.getInstance(props,
        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("xyz@gmail.com", "abc2014!");//change accordingly
                //return new PasswordAuthentication("abc@gmail.com", "abc2014");//change accordingly                
            }
        }); 

        //compose message  
        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session2);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from,name));//change accordingly  
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(to));
            message.setSubject(subject +" " +name);
            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(from,name));//change accordingly 
            message.setText(" Name: "+name+"\n Email :"+from+"\n Phone No :"+phone+"\n Message : "+messageText);

            System.out.println("before sent message" + to);

            //send message  
            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("message sent successfully" + to);

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        out.println("Mail was sent to " + to);
    %>

</body>
</html>
```

Above is my Jsp file for sending mail request to my email id from my website contact Form But When i send mail through my webSite i am getting exception as below. It is working Fine when i am using it in my local Machine But Throws Exception when deployed on server.  Please help to resolve this. Thanks in Advance:

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /sendMail.jsp at line 62

```
59:                     System.out.println("message sent successfully" + to);
60:
61:             } catch (MessagingException e) {
62:                     throw new RuntimeException(e);
63:             }
64:
65:             out.println("Mail was sent to " + to);


Stacktrace:] with root cause
 javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed;
  nested exception is:
        class javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:218)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:80)
        at org.apache.jsp.sendMail_jsp._jspService(sendMail_jsp.java:154)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2440)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: what version of java are you running on machine and what version on server??

Comment: server java version: 1.7.0_111  
local version: 1.7

Comment: is it an option to upgrade both to java8?

Comment: But it is working fine on local with 1.7 version

Comment: on different versions of JDK the priority of securty providers seems to be different. You can disable the DH provider from your jdk, edit jre/lib/security/java.security -> jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms= DH

Comment: Another solution would be to use https://www.bouncycastle.org implementation of security providers... Download these jars: bcprov-jdk15on-152.jar and bcprov-ext-jdk15on-152.jar, Copy jars to WEB-INF/lib (or your classpath), Add provider dynamically: import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider; .... Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

Comment: Thanks .. will Try